# Is there an alternative to evalInSandbox?

Tags: firefox-addon

Is there an alternative to using [evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.evalInSandbox)?

The purpose is running an external JS script in a safe environment.
The merits of `evalInSandbox` (good or bad) is not in question.

Comment: for what goal? which of its behavioral properties do you need? which of its properties do you dislike that you seek an alternative? please expand your question, it's hard to provide an alternative if you don't describe the underlying requirements.

Comment: For running an external JS script in a safe environment, bearing in mind that "Access to the 'evalInSandbox' property is deprecated for security or other reasons."

Answer (score 0):

> "Access to the 'evalInSandbox' property is deprecated for security or other reasons."

If you're referring to the AMO validator, see [this mozilla forums thread](https://forums.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4521), it seems  that the warning is imprecise, it's meant to highlight a potential security risk if that method is used improperly.

Comment: Yes... but nonetheless, as the title says, I am looking to see if there is an  alternative, regardless of whether there is any problem with `evalInSandbox` or not.

Comment: I asked for a reason why you're looking. You provided one. I outlined why it's bogus. So... is there another problem?

Comment: Once again, the reason is irrelevant. I am looking for an alternative to evalInSandbox. I am already aware of alone possible alternative. I am checking for ALL THE POSSIBILITIES. If you are aware of an alternative, please reply.